# What is a better way for ReactJS component reuse?

Tags: reactjs

In my render of my ReactJS component, I have a lot of duplication.  I would like to be able to remove that duplication.

Here's the trimmed down version of the component:

```
export default class PageBody extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);  

        this.state = {
            displayState: 0         
        };      
    }

    render() {

        const whichLayout = this.state.displayState;
        let resultLayout = null;
        switch(whichLayout) {
            case 1:
                resultLayout =  <div><Toolbar /><br /><PortfolioBody /></div>
                break;
            default:
                resultLayout =  <div><Toolbar /><br /><DefaultBody /></div>
                break;
        }

        return (resultLayout);
    }
}
```

What I thought would be a good idea is to concatenate resultLayout, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
let resultLayout = <div><Toolbar /><br />;
        switch(whichLayout) {
            case 1:
                resultLayout =  resultLayout + <PortfolioBody />
                break;
            default:
                resultLayout =  resultLayout + <DefaultBody />
                break;
        }
 resultLayout = </div>;
```

Thoughts?

Thank you
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<PortfolioBody />`  is not a string, you cannot concatenate it. It is equivalent to `React.createElement(PortfoliaBody)`, which returns an *object*.

Instead, assign the part that can change to a variable and include that in the JSX:

```
export default class PageBody extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);  

        this.state = {
            displayState: 0         
        };      
    }

    render() {

        const whichLayout = this.state.displayState;
        let resultLayout = null;
        switch(whichLayout) {
            case 1:
                resultLayout =  <PortfolioBody />;
                break;
            default:
                resultLayout =  <DefaultBody />;
                break;
        }

        return (
          <div>
            <Toolbar />
            <br />
            {resultLayout}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

Or more streamlined:

```
const layouts = {
  1: PortfolioBody,
};

export default class PageBody extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);  

        this.state = {
            displayState: 0         
        };      
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Toolbar />
            <br />
            {React.createElement(layouts[this.state.displayState] || DefaultBody)}
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a `jsx` not a `string`, since Toolbar is common, so you can `render` that directly and use the logic for another component.

Write it like this:

```
render() {

    const whichLayout = this.state.displayState;
    let resultLayout = null;
    switch(whichLayout) {
        case 1:
            resultLayout =  <PortfolioBody />
            break;
        default:
            resultLayout =  <DefaultBody />
            break;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Toolbar />
            <br />
            {resultLayout}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Or you can improve it one more level by putting the `switch` part in another method and call that method from `render`.

Like this:

```
renderComponent(){
    switch(this.state.displayState) {
        case 1: return <PortfolioBody />;
        default: return <DefaultBody />
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Toolbar />
            <br />
            {this.renderComponent()}
        </div>
    );
}
```